# How to handle form submit in React with multiple input values without using controlled input or we can say without useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I am building html form in react with dynamic json data and I want to write a handlesubmit function without using useState, is there any way we can achieve this?

Comment: check out this article [Easy React Forms with FormData by dfg...](https://danielfgray.com/articles/ez-react-forms)

Answer (score 1):

> We can easily get form data from event fired at the time of form submission. We can convert the event of form into FormData as shown in below code, and we can send FromData with our API.

Event has all the information about for form inputs with the help of the name attribute in the input element.

```
<form onSubmit={ev => {
ev.preventDefault()
const body = new FormData(ev.currentTarget)
fetch('/update-profile', { method: 'post', body })}}>
```

Comment: How is this different from the article posted above ?